# singleton variables in prolog query

Tags: prolog

I am new to Prolog and running into a problem. When I ask the query `?-grandfather(daniel,george)` on the data below, I get the wrong answer. I don't understand why my query doesn't work. I also received a warning message stating that *[C,D] are singleton variables*. This warning no longer occurs. Again, I'm unsure why.

```
mother(jules,mary).
mother(jules,martha).
mother(jules,andy).
mother(mary,annie).
mother(mary,george).
mother(martha,jesse).
mother(martha,june).
mother(june,camile).
father(daniel,mary).
father(daniel,martha).
father(daniel,andy).
father(adrian,annie).
father(adrian,george).
father(carlo,camile).

brothers(A,B):-father(C,A),father(C,B);mother(D,A),mother(D,B).

grandfather(E,W):-father(E,father(C,W));father(E,mother(D,W)).
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write your grandfather query more simply:

```
grandfather(E,W):-father(E,A),father(A,W).
grandfather(E,W):-father(E,A),mother(A,W).
```

or

```
grandfather(E,W):-father(E,A),father(A,W);father(E,A),mother(A,W).
```

and now:

```
6 ?- grandfather(daniel,george).
true .
7 ?- grandfather(daniel,annie).
true .
```

Here, we ask Prolog to find the grandson of E where: E is the father of A and A is the father/mother of W.

Or more specifically, to check if daniel has a grandson named george. Prolog checks: daniel has a daughter mary and mary has a son george. So it would return true. If you `trace` it, you see:

```
[trace] 3 ?- grandfather(daniel,george).
   Call: (6) grandfather(daniel, george) ? creep
   Call: (7) father(daniel, _G1931) ? creep
   Exit: (7) father(daniel, mary) ? creep
   Call: (7) father(mary, george) ? creep
   Fail: (7) father(mary, george) ? creep
   Redo: (7) father(daniel, _G1931) ? creep
   Exit: (7) father(daniel, martha) ? creep
   Call: (7) father(martha, george) ? creep
   Fail: (7) father(martha, george) ? creep
   Redo: (7) father(daniel, _G1931) ? creep
   Exit: (7) father(daniel, andy) ? creep
   Call: (7) father(andy, george) ? creep
   Fail: (7) father(andy, george) ? creep
   Redo: (6) grandfather(daniel, george) ? creep
   Call: (7) father(daniel, _G1931) ? creep
   Exit: (7) father(daniel, mary) ? creep
   Call: (7) mother(mary, george) ? creep
   Exit: (7) mother(mary, george) ? creep
   Exit: (6) grandfather(daniel, george) ? creep
true .
```

`[C,D] are singleton variables` indicates that there is one or more variable in the clause that appears only once. This isn't affecting the program, you can still run your queries.

[Singleton Variables on SWI Documentation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/SingletonVar.html)

Answer (score 0):

> Thanks for the answer, one last question, i tried to do a rule for cousins like this
>
> cousins(X,Y):-mother(A,X),mother(B,Y),mother(D,A),mother(D,B),father(C,A),father(C,B).
>
> it states that if the mother of X and the mother of Y have the same mother and father X,Y are cousins. but when i ask the query ?- cousins(annie,george) prolog answers YES, and it should not be that way because annie and george are brothers, so i guess there must be a logical mistake

A and B (Mothers of X and Y) can be equal, that is why it gives Yes to brothers.

You should specify that they don't have the same mother and father (A\=B).

---

**Off question:**

Using "parent" can reduce your coding in this kind of problems (family trees).

```
mother(A,B) :- parent(A,B).
```

Or even:

```
mother(A,B) :- parent(A,B), female(A).
```

This way you don't need to apply the cousin problem (or any of this kind, like brothers) to the mother and the father.

In the brothers you have:

```
brothers(A,B):-father(C,A),father(C,B);mother(D,A),mother(D,B).
```

It could be:

```
brothers(A,B):-parent(X,A),parent(X,B).
```